# getting table which is within a row of another apparent table using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The table I'm looking to scrape seems to be within a row within a table and I can't quite figure out how to get it out.

The url is:

http://www.irishstatutebook.ie/eli/2019/si/497/made/en/print?q=Electricity+Regulation+Act+1999&years=2019

I'm struggling and trying to learn how to use BeautifulSoup but there don't seem to be any examples which run into this problem!

The table I'm trying to extract is the first table, with first row header being "(1) Ref No."

Comment: Hi, perhaps getting the outer table, then calling `.find` on that element would work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script to get data from the first table (and print it to the screen):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.irishstatutebook.ie/eli/2019/si/497/made/en/print?q=Electricity+Regulation+Act+1999&years=2019'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

data = []
table = soup.select_one('table.t1') # <-- select first table

for tr in table.select('tr'):
    data.append([*map(lambda td: td.get_text(strip=True), tr.select('td'))])

# print the table:
from textwrap import shorten
for row in data:
    print(('{:<10}' + '{:<33}' * 6).format(*[shorten(data, 33) for data in row]))
```

Prints:

```
(1) Ref. No.(2) REFIT Power Purchase [...]   (3) Supplier                     (4) Electricity generator        (5) Generation plant Description (6) Energy source of electricity (7) Capacity accepted into [...] 
1         REFIT 1/5/1                      Bord Gáis Energy Limited         Jaroma Windfarm Ltd.             Toomyvara, Ballinlough, Co. [...]Small Scale Wind Project         2.550                            
2         REFIT 1/5/2                      Viridian Energy Limited*         Reirk Energy Ltd.                Dromdeeveen, Ballagh, Co. [...]  Large Scale Wind Project         10.500                           
3         REFIT 1/5/4                      Bord Gáis Energy Limited         Adeery Hydro                     Killybegs, Co. Donegal           Hydro Project                    0.400                            
4         REFIT 1/5/5                      Viridian Energy Limited*         Bawnmore Windfarm Ltd            Carriganima, Macroom, Co. Cork   Large Scale Wind Project         14.990                           
5         REFIT 1/5/6                      Viridian Energy Limited*         Muingnaminnane Windfarms Ltd.    Muingnaminnane, Kielduff, [...]  Large Scale Wind Project         15.300                           
6         REFIT 1/5/8                      ESBIE t/a Electric Ireland Ltd   Mountainlodge Power Ltd.         Mountain Lodge Co. Cavan         Large Scale Wind Project         24.800                           
7         REFIT 1/5/9                      Viridian Energy Limited*         Tra Investments Ltd.             Ballincollig Hill and [...]      Large Scale Wind Project         13.300                           
8         REFIT 1/5/20                     SSE Airtricity Limited           Carrig Wind Farm Ltd.            Lacka, Carrig, Birr, Co. Offaly  Small Scale Wind Project         2.550                            

...and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc

url = 'http://www.irishstatutebook.ie/eli/2019/si/497/made/en/print?q=Electricity+Regulation+Act+1999&years=2019'
html = requests.get(url).text
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
table = doc.getElement('table',attr='class',value='t1')
trs = table.trs
for tr in trs:
  print ([td.text for td in tr.tds])
```

Result:

```
['(1) Ref. No.', '(2) REFIT Power Purchase Agreement Reference', '(3) Supplier', '(4) Electricity generator', '(5) Generation plant Description', '(6) Energy source of electricity', '(7) Capacity accepted into REFIT (MW)']
['1', 'REFIT 1/5/1', 'Bord GÃ¡is Energy Limited', 'Jaroma Windfarm Ltd.', 'Toomyvara, Ballinlough, Co. Tipperary', 'Small Scale Wind Project', '2.550']
['2', 'REFIT 1/5/2', 'Viridian Energy Limited*', 'Reirk Energy Ltd.', 'Dromdeeveen, Ballagh, Co. Limerick', 'Large Scale Wind Project', '10.500']
['3', 'REFIT 1/5/4', 'Bord GÃ¡is Energy Limited', 'Adeery Hydro', 'Killybegs, Co. Donegal', 'Hydro Project', '0.400']
['4', 'REFIT 1/5/5', 'Viridian Energy Limited*', 'Bawnmore Windfarm Ltd', 'Carriganima, Macroom, Co. Cork', 'Large Scale Wind Project', '14.990']
['5', 'REFIT 1/5/6', 'Viridian Energy Limited*', 'Muingnaminnane Windfarms Ltd.', 'Muingnaminnane, Kielduff, Tralee, Co. Kerry', 'Large Scale Wind Project', '15.300']
['6', 'REFIT 1/5/8', 'ESBIE t/a Electric Ireland Ltd', 'Mountainlodge Power Ltd.', 'Mountain Lodge Co. Cavan', 'Large Scale Wind Project', '24.800']
['7', 'REFIT 1/5/9', 'Viridian Energy Limited*', 'Tra Investments Ltd.', 'Ballincollig Hill and Maghanknockane, Tralee, Co. Kerry', 'Large Scale Wind Project', '13.300']
['8', 'REFIT 1/5/20', 'SSE Airtricity Limited', 'Carrig Wind Farm Ltd.', 'Lacka, Carrig, Birr, Co. Offaly', 'Small Scale Wind Project', '2.550']
['9', 'REFIT 1/5/23', 'Viridian Energy Limited*', 'Pallas Windfarm Ltd', 'Pallas, Banemore, Listowel, Co. Kerry', 'Large Scale Wind Project', '37.850']
... and so on.
```

You can get the examples of SimplifiedDoc [here](https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples)